# How to detect system power events such as suspend, hibernate, etc

Tags: linux, events, acpi

I want to make a Linux application that send a message to a remote host when a local system (where the application runs) is going to suspend, hibernate or shutdown. I googled how to do this and found acpi_listen but it doesn't work.

Here is the result of `ps aux | grep acpi` on the system I tested (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS):

```
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec03   0:00 [kacpid]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec03   0:00 [kacpi_notify]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec03   0:00 [kacpi_hotplug]
root       934  0.0  0.0   2048   872 ?        Ss   Dec03   0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
```

Communicating with acpid directly via a UNIX domain socket wouldn't work since that's the way acpi_listen works, although I didn't try it. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listen for them [over D-Bus](https://serverfault.com/questions/199895/how-can-i-flush-my-ssh-keys-on-power-management-activity/199896#199896).